# MSBuild is not installed on TFS controller when I installed VS 2017

Tags: tfs, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, installation

I have installed Visual Studio 2017 and I don't see the MSBuild.exe installed.

What are the options I need to check for MSBuild to be installed?

Comment: Could you get the MSBuild.exe in your side? Any update, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referece MSDN: [MSBuild 15](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/what-s-new-in-msbuild-15-0)

The path for MSBuild.exe has been changed and is no longer installed in the GAC.
MSBuild 15 is also now part of the [.NET Core SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download).

If you installed **Visual Studio 2017** then it will be under the VS installation path. For example, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild.

You can also use the following PowerShell module to locate MSBuild: [vssetup.powershell](https://github.com/Microsoft/vssetup.powershell).

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [Build Tools for Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017) and you don't need to install Visual Studio on your TFS Controller

Answer (score 1):

> What are the options I need to check for MSBuild to be installed?

According to the Microsoft blog [MSBuild is now part of Visual Studio!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2013/07/24/msbuild-is-now-part-of-visual-studio/):

> Starting with Visual Studio 2013, the 2013 version of MSBuild will
>   ship as a part of Visual Studio instead of the .NET Framework.

So, if you have installed the Visual Studio 2017, the MSBuild.exe should be located at following path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise(Professional or Community )\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
```